# Generic function with structs

Tags: ios, swift

I try to create reusable function. It select data only for current week. But I need use this function few times in my app, so I've decided to do it generic.

I have two structs

```
struct BodyWeightCalendarModel {
    let weight: Float
    let date: Date
}

struct RetrievedWorkoutsByExercise {
    
    let exerciseTitle: String
    let sets: Int
    let maxWeight: Int
    let maxReps: Int
    let date: Date
    let volume: Int
    
}


 func loopForWeek<T> (data: [T], completionHandler: ([T]) -> Void)  {
        
        let arrayForPeriod2: [T] = []
        
        for value in data where value.date >= (calendar.currentWeekBoundary()?.startOfWeek)! && value.date <= (calendar.currentWeekBoundary()?.endOfWeek)!  {
            arrayForPeriod.append(value)
        }
        completionHandler(arrayForPeriod2)
    }
```

How to get access to data values? I can't get access through "value.data".
So I want to use this function for different struct (but all this structs needs to have field "date").

Comment: A generic type T doesn't have a date value.  I'm struggling to understand your thinking, but if you want to abstract it I think the solution you're looking for would be better performed with a protocol with a date field in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers using a protocol with date property makes most sense in your case. However theoretically you could also use keypaths to achieve that. You could make a function that takes any instances and gets dates from them in a similar way as below:

```
func printDates(data: [Any], keyPath:AnyKeyPath)  {
    for value in data {
        if let date = value[keyPath: keyPath] as? Date {
            print("date = \(date)")
        }
    }
}
```

and then pass for example your BodyWeightCalendarModel instances as below:

```
let one = BodyWeightCalendarModel(date: Date(), weight: 1)
let two = BodyWeightCalendarModel(date: Date(), weight: 2)
printDates(data: [one, two], keyPath: \BodyWeightCalendarModel.date)
```

But still a protocol makes more sense in your case.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't access `value.date` is that your function knows nothing about `T`. Your function declares `T` but it doesn't constrain it. To the compiler, `T` can be anything.

You need to create a protocol that tells your function what to expect, and make your structs conform to it:

```
protocol Timed { // You might find a better name
    var date: Date { get }
}

struct BodyWeightCalendarModel: Timed {
    let date: Date
    ...
}

struct RetrievedWorkoutsByExercise: Timed {
    let date: Date
    ...
}
```

Now you can constrain `T` to `Timed` and your function will know that `value` has a `date` property.

```
func loopForWeek<T: Timed> (data: [T], completionHandler: ([T]) -> Void)  {
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is close. A Generic value doesn't necessarily have a value on it called `date` so this won't work. What you can do instead is create a protocol that has a variable of date on it. With that protocol you can do something neat with an extension.

```swift
protocol Dated {
    var date: Date { get set }
}

extension Dated {
    func loopForWeek() -> [Dated] {
          let arrayForPeriod2: [Dated] = []
        
          for value in date >= (calendar.currentWeekBoundary()?.startOfWeek)! && value.date <= (calendar.currentWeekBoundary()?.endOfWeek)!  {
            arrayForPeriod.append(value)
        }
        return arrayForPeriod2
    }
}
```

Then we can make your two structs use that protocol like:

```swift
struct BodyWeightCalendarModel: Dated {
    let date: Date
}

struct RetrievedWorkoutsByExercise: Dated {
    let date: Date
}
```

And they can call the function like:

```swift
let workouts = RetrievedWorkoutsByExercise()
let result = workouts.loopForWeek()
```